# Добавление нескольких иконок в pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Создавая *.exe* файл с помощью pyinstaller есть возможность добавить свою иконку в конечный файл через параметр `--icon`. Но таким образом добавляется только одна иконка, а для корректного её отображения должно быть несколько иконок разного размера. Как я могу добавить в конечный файл несколько изображений *.ico*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [ICOBundle](http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/ICOBundle), чтобы из нескольких `.ico` создать один:

```
icobundl.exe -o main.ico main16x16.ico main32x32.ico
```

---

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808600/make-several-pngs-into-one-ico-file)